# Optimizing MERA disentanglers to represent a specific state

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, renormalization, tensor-network

I've read multiple papers (e.g. https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.79.144108) on the multiscale entanglement renormalization ansatz (MERA) where algorithms are given for how to optimize a MERA tensor network to minimize the energy of a given Hamiltonian. I'm wondering whether a systematic approach exists to find a good MERA representation for a particular *state* $|\psi\rangle$ (given as a normal wavefunction) that we want to represent. (e.g. for MPS one can do Schmidt decompositions as described in https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.91.147902). I understand that the isometries can be chosen to just take the highest weight vectors, but how does one in general optimize the disentangling layers? Is there a good reference for this?

*Edit: I originally stated carelessly that Schmidt decomposition is an example for how to find the best MPS representation of a state; this was incorrect as pointed out in the comment below.

Comment: The Schmidt decomposition does not necessarily give the best approximation for MPS!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Thanks for pointing this out! I was careless about this in my original post and have edited it accordingly. In general, though, is there even a scheme like Schmidt decomposition to efficiently find a good (though not necessarily optimal) MERA representation for a particular state?

Comment: The notion of efficiency is subtle here since the full state is anyway an exponentially big object.  A key point which distinguishes MERA from MPS is the unitary of the tensors.  This is a non-linear constraint which makes the optimization more subtle (and, well, nonlinear).